# Javascript framework support in phonegap for cross-platform?

Tags: phonegap-plugins

Anyone have the idea of which Javascript framework is much supported by the cross platform
for PhoneGap App development.

I search on the web and find the JQuery Mobile framework but it is not much compatible with the android it shows problem with UI while it is much supported by the iPhone.

There is any JSframwork supported by the all max platform?

Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

I personally use DataZombie's fork of jQTouch - https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch

The transitions and scrolling all work fine on Android unlike some of the others.

Android doesn't have a built-in theme for Android the way it does for iOS, but I was able to put one together for my app fairly easily (it's just CSS and a few images). When it is more complete I will probably release it, but you should be able to do your own or use the jet one (that looks fairly Android-ish).

None of the frameworks really looks like a proper native Android app out of the box as far as I have been able to tell. Nearly all of them seem to have a very iOS-centric navigation system (back buttons in nab bars, etc) that just don't exist in native Android apps. One of the first things I did in my theme was to get rid of any back buttons thus relying on the hardware back button for backward navigation (more like what Android users expect).

Comment: yes, that's why i am using the core java script+css3+html5, but using core java script is tedious and tough job.

Comment: I hear you. I actually started work on my own Android-friendly html5/css3/js framework from scratch, but realised I could get what I wanted just by taking what I had learned and theming jQTouch. I am hoping to release the Android theme sometime in the new year.

Comment: Why don't you try ionic framework. It's like phonegap but it uses angularjs as the framework.

Comment: @GutierrezDev this answer is almost 4 years old. Ionic was probably not even a glint in Max's eye at the time ;) I have long since moved away from using any UI framework. They were all terrible at the time, so I just ended up learning how to do my own html/css/js instead.